# How the iterator is invalid in a vector for erase function if i handling it?

Tags: stl

Here is my code

```
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  int i=1;
  for ( i=1; i<=50; i++) myvector.push_back(i);
  for ( i=0; i<50; i++) 
  {
      if(myvector[i]%2==0)
        {
            myvector.erase(myvector.begin()+i);
            i--;
        }
  }
```

Here i am trying to remove all the even numbers and after erasing an even number i am adjustingthe counter variable. But i am not getting the desired result.Why?

Comment: The loop still goes up to `i == 49` even though there aren't 50 elements in the container.  Perhaps you should work from the end of the vector toward the beginning?  Or use the `vector::erase()` with the `remove_if()` function template from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: THanx..i got it     for ( i=0; i<myvector.size(); i++) 
  {
      if(myvector[i]%2==0)
        {
            myvector.erase(myvector.begin()+i);
            i--;
        }
  }

Answer (score 0):

The second suggestion from Michael makes much more sense than doing it manually:

```
std::vector<int> myvector;
myvector.erase(std::remove_if(myvector.begin(), 
                              myvector.end(),
                              [](int x){return x % 2 == 0;}),
               myvector.end());
```